# Xulrunner не открывает ссылку

Tags: c#, redirect

У меня не открывается ссылка после редиректа а высвечивается такая ерунда:
chrome://global/content/commonDialog.xul в адресной строке. How fix it? c#

Comment: У вас нет никаких расширений браузера? Попробуйте их отключить.

Comment: Нет просто подключена библиотека. commonDialog.xul выводит кнопки "Ок" и "Отмена" - встроенное окно видимо.